Trouble with regex negative lookahead
These are my test strings:
getObject('modSnippet')
getObject($prefix . 'modSnippet'
getObject($classPrefix . 'modSnippet'

I want to match the first one, but not the other two.
I've tried both of these:
(?!prefix|Prefix)getObject
getObject(?!prefix|Prefix)

But both match all three test strings. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't seem to make this work.

Which regex flavor are you using?

Why do you think you need a negative lookahead? Can't you just use the regex getObject\('[^']*'\) or even just getObject\([^$]?

@Socowi I think it's apparent from the OP's attempts that the goal is to exclude strings with a specific prefix.

@blhsing I understood as much. But looking at OP's test strings, it seems like an XY problem to me. I thought OP's actual goal might have been solvable without explicitly excluding a multi-character string.

A lookahead pattern should be placed at where the sub-pattern matches. In your test strings there are non-word characters followed by getObject before prefix may occur so the sub-pattern in your lookahead assertion should account for those non-word characters, as well as those word characters that may optionally precede prefix:
getObject(?!\W+\w*[Pp]refix)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2k2jE3/1

Perfect, and very well explained. Thanks! I was confused by the term "lookahead" and assumed that it would do what it says and look ahead to disqualify the pattern.
